# Native iOS application Development using Worklight API and JSON parser with HTTP Adapter

Tags: objective-c, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-adapters, worklight-server

```
WLProcedureInvocationData *myInvocationData = [[WLProcedureInvocationData alloc] initWithAdapterName:@"myRESTAdapter" procedureName:@"getAgents"];

MyInvokeListener *invokeListener = [[MyInvokeListener alloc] initWithController: self];

[[WLClient sharedInstance] invokeProcedure:myInvocationData withDelegate:invokeListener];
```

> [__NSDictionaryI WLJSONRepresentation]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance

I am trying to fetch the response using JSON service with HTTP Adapter in Worklight. When i deploy the API and proceeds further then am getting the above exception..

Note: The service am using only to fetch details with out any parameter parsing...

**Adapter code**:

```
function getAgents() {
    var input = {
        method : 'get',
        returnedContentType : 'json',
        path : 'myApp/agents'
    };

    return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
}
```

Can anyone help on this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you edit the relevant code into the question please?

Comment: this is not invoking my listener....

Comment: Hello - as requested - please can you edit your code into the question? It's very hard to read when you put it in a comment.

Comment: @user3035879 as i can see from the exception its not related to client side just post your server side code.

Comment: #my Js func in Eclipse
function getAgents() {
    var input = {
     method : 'get',
     returnedContentType : 'json',
     path : 'myApp/agents',
     
    };
 return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
}

Comment: Where is `WLJSONRepresentation` being called?  The error is saying that you tried to call that method on an object that was a `NSDictionary`, which doesn't have such a method.

Comment: I am not using any dictionary... I am just trying to invoke the HTTPAdapter in JSON format from eclipse through Worklight.

Comment: Let me try asking that again: where is `WLJSONRepresentation` being called?  Something somewhere in your code or the libraries that your code uses is calling it on the wrong type of object.  Try setting up a breakpoint that triggers on an Objective-C exception and look at the stack to see how you got there.

Comment: I understand the question. WLJSONRepresentation or JSONRepresentation is not being used in my project....

Comment: @user3035879 can you post the code of `MyInvokeListener`

Comment: - (id)initWithController: (pageViewController *) mainView {
    if ( self = [super init] ){
        vc = mainView;
    }
    return self;
}

Comment: //onSuccess callback - called when the adapter Invocation finsih successfully.
-(void)onSuccess:(WLResponse *)response {
    NSLog(@"\nProcedure Invocation Success: -------------------------");
    //Retrive the JSON response.
    NSDictionary *responseDict = [response getResponseJson];
    NSArray *itemsArray = [responseDict objectForKey:@"ROOT"];
    NSLog(@"ROOT:: %@" , itemsArray);
    for (int i=0; i<[itemsArray count]; i++){
        NSDictionary *itemDict = [itemsArray objectAtIndex:i];
        NSLog(@"Title :: %@" , [itemDict objectForKey:@"title"]);
    }
}

Comment: //onFailure callback - called when the adapter Invocation failed.
-(void)onFailure:(WLFailResponse *)response{
    NSString *resultText = @"Invocation failure. ";
    if ([response responseText] != nil){
        resultText = [resultText stringByAppendingString:[response responseText]];
    }
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No network connection"    message:@"Please check your network connection and make sure the adapter been deployed."      delegate:nil     cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"  otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}

Comment: i am stuck @  [[WLClient sharedInstance] invokeProcedure:myInvocationData withDelegate:invokeListener];                                                Got an exception at this point......  Not entering into onSuccess or onFailure methods...

Comment: Please provide the project so we could debug it.